# `pip list --outdated` doesn't list pip itself

Tags: python, pip

If I do:

```
% pip list --outdated
```

I don't see `pip` itself listed there, even though I purposefully installed and confirmed that I'm running an older version of `pip`.

How can I check if `pip` itself needs to be updated?

(If it's relevant: I have to install `pip` with `--ignore-installed` because I'm running under miniconda3.)

Comment: This must be an issue with conda, as `pip` lists itself just fine. `python3.6 -m venv foo && source foo/bin/activate && pip list --outdated` prints `pip` and `setuptools` as expected.

Comment: Cheers @hoefling, I've raised this as an issue [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7885).

Comment: looks like `pip show pip` lists some different `pip`, can you compare their locations? `pip show pip` should print the location line, also you can issue `pip show -f pip` to list all files belonging to the package. I'm not familiar with conda, unfortunately - maybe it has some kind of global `pip` installation that lists not itself, but some env-specific `pip`?

Comment: @hoefling Thanks: `show -f` lists files from `18.1` even if `pip --vers` shows `10.0.1`.